# How to remove a role in discord.py without discord.ext

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to remove a role from a user without using discord.ext ( because of certain resons I can't ) but I don't know how to do it ( so without commands ( by commands I mean @bot.commands....), and without ctx )

If you want this is the code where I want to put the thing that will remove the role :

```
            if message.content.startswith('$rmv_role'):
                member4 = message.content
                member5 = member4.split()
                member6 = member5[1]
                server_id = message.guild.id
                guild = client.get_guild(server_id)
                role_id = 999988854696194048
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
                await message.delete() 
                user_id = ''.join(c for c in member6 if c.isdigit())
                user = get(bot.get_all_members(), id=user_id)
                *the code that remove roles*
                return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.Member` has a method called [`remove_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.Member.remove_roles).

So, the code is following:

```py
await user.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: Error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  
File "c:\Users\****\Downloads\proto bot a.py", line 93, in on_message
    await user.remove_roles(role)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Comment: @UniversGamer It can't find the user, the code above is correct. The error shows another problem, that `user` is None. Could have several reasons.